# XMLHttpRequest in for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make several server requests inside a for loop. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445809/how-to-handle-simultaneous-javascript-xmlhttprequests) and implemented the suggested solution. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
    (function(i) {
    if(<some conditions>)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp[i]=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp[i]=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp[i].onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp[i].readyState==4 && xmlhttp[i].status==200) {
          document.getElementById("preselection").innerHTML=xmlhttp[i].responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp[i].open("GET","getBuoys.php?q="+i,true);
      xmlhttp[i].send();
    }
})(i);
}
```

If I remove the for loop and change all xmlhttp[i] to xmlhttp, everything works just fine for one element, but I can't make several requests. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Check the answer below or check this answer [sending-post-request-in-for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773307/sending-post-request-in-for-loop/24774532#24774532) for further explanation.

Comment: Have you defined `xmlhttp` to be an array somewhere? If yes, what is the error message that you are getting? If no, why don't you make every single `xmlhttp` local to the closure scope?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the snippet below

```
// JavaScript
window.onload = function(){

    var f = (function(){
        var xhr = [], i;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //for loop
            (function(i){
                xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
                url = "closure.php?data=" + i;
                xhr[i].open("GET", url, true);
                xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xhr[i].readyState === 4 && xhr[i].status === 200){
                        console.log('Response from request ' + i + ' [ ' + xhr[i].responseText + ']'); 
                    }
                };
                xhr[i].send();
            })(i);
        }
    })();

};

// PHP [closure.php]
echo "Hello Kitty -> " . $_GET["data"];
```

Response

```
Response from request 0 [ Hello Kitty -> 0]
Response from request 1 [ Hello Kitty -> 1]
Response from request 2 [ Hello Kitty -> 2]
```

Comment: Ah so the mistake was to declare the array globally. Maybe this is already enough for me, although Lawrence Jones answer looks also very nice. I can't try out your answer right now, will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Axel Basically yes ;) Check the other reference I left in the comments to see this issue in more details and not using an array.

Comment: +1 for sending the for loop variable as a self-invoking function variable, so not affected by async delay, helped me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, that's awful formatting. A small request to keep it a bit more parseable in future please.

We can clean this up though.

```
var XMLHttpRequest
  = XMLHttpRequest || require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;

// Makes a request for 4 buoy page responses.
requestAllBuoys(4, function(requests) {

  console.log('Got results!');

  // Take out the responses, they are collected in the order they were
  // requested.
  responses = requests.map(function(request) {
    return request.responseText;
  });

  // Left to you to implement- I don't know what you're going to do with
  // your page!
  updateDom(responses);

});

// Makes request to all buoy url's, calling the given callback once
// all have completed with an array of xmlRequests.
function requestAllBuoys (n, cb) {

  var latch = makeLatch(n, cb);

  makeBuoyURLTo(n).map(function (url, i) {
    startXMLRequest('GET', url, latch.bind(undefined, i));
  });

}

// Generates a latch function, that will execute the given callback
// only once the function it returns has been called n times.
function makeLatch (n, cb) {

  var remaining = n,
      results = [],
      countDown;

  countDown = function (i, result) {
    results[i] = result;
    if (--remaining == 0 && typeof cb == 'function') {
      cb(results);
    }
  }

  return countDown;

}

// Generates an array of buoy URL's from 1 to n.
function makeBuoyURLTo (n) {

  var i, buoyUrls = [];

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    buoyUrls.push('getBuoys.php?q=' + i);
  }

  return buoyUrls;

}

// Create and initiate an XMLRequest, with the given method to the given url.
// The optional callback will be called on successful completion.
function startXMLRequest (method, url, cb) {

  var xmlRequest = createXMLRequest();

  xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (isXMLFinished(xmlRequest)) {
      if (cb && typeof cb == 'function') {
        cb(xmlRequest, method, url);
      }
    }
  }

  xmlRequest.open(method, url, true);
  xmlRequest.send();

  return xmlRequest;

}

// Initiates an XMLRequest from either HTML5 native, or MS ActiveX depending
// on what is available.
function createXMLRequest () {

  var xmlRequest;

  if (XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }

  return xmlRequest;

}

// Verifies that XMLRequest has finished, with a status 200 (OK).
function isXMLFinished (xmlRequest) {
  return (xmlRequest.readyState == 4) && (xmlRequest.status == 200);
}
```

This may seem longer, but it makes things infinitely clearer, and the time you spent making it so is time you don't spend debugging.

It also allows you to access the final result together, in the order that they came as a standard array. This is the main added bulk.

I would say you have a good idea of what you're actually doing here, as to me the only thing about your code that wouldn't *work* is the updating of the dom (surely you'll just be assigning them rapidly all into the same element? replacing each other each time...).

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754367/handling-multiple-call-asynchronous-callbacks/20754638#20754638) about handling async callbacks if you're still struggling. But please, for your own sake, keep your code cleaner.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow as soon as I got time. Looks very nice and organized by the way!